# Selecting objects to satisfy a requirements chain

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have nodes each of which can generate and/or consume typed resources. Given a particular node, I want to generate any/all directed graphs of nodes starting from nodes that consume nothing that ultimately satisfy all the resource requirements of the particular node (and the requirements of all other nodes in the graph too).

**Trivial Example:**

```
A generates r1
B generates r2 and r3
C generates r3 and r4 and consumes r1
D consumes r4
...
```

To make `D` I could use the graph `A -> C -> D`

There could be more than one way of making D.
The problem is similar to, but not that solved by topological sorting.

I am after some names for this problem that I can research.

Thanks.

Comment: can a node consume multiple resources?

Comment: Does it need to be the shortest path too? For example if D consumed r3 instead of r4, it could meet its requirement by just using B, or it could use C, but that would also require A. Are both valid solutions?

Comment: A single node might need more than one direct node to supply it's requested resources, or might consume only part of its feeder nodes resources.

Being able to iterate through solutions would be enough, BUT I THINK I CAN SOLVE MY PROBLEM,I just would like to know it's more official name, and how others solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I have "[Program evaluation and review technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_evaluation_and_review_technique)" as a subject to review.